# AWS S3's getSignedUrl for put object returns 403

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, cloud

I am trying to get a **pre-signed URL** to upload files to the S3 bucket. Here is my workflow:

**1. Invoke Lambda** -> **2. Get pre-signed URL** -> **3. Hit the URL (PUT) with file**

**1. Invoke Lambda**

I made sure the AWS keys have the correct permission. In fact, it has full access. Here is the Source code:

```
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: '*****************',
  secretAccessKey: '*****************',
  region: 'us-east-1',
  signatureVersion: 'v4'
});

let requestObject = JSON.parse(event["body"]);
let fileName = requestObject.fileName;
let fileType = requestObject.fileType;
const myBucket = 'jobobo-resumes';

s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
"Bucket": myBucket,
"Key": fileName,
"ContentType": fileType
}, function (err, url) {

  if (err) {    
  mainCallback(null, err);
  } else {    
  mainCallback(null, url);    
  }

}
```

So, I am getting the filename, file type(MIME) from the request and use that to create the signature.

**2. Get pre-signed URL**
When I hit the Lambda I get the pre-signed URL. Now, I will use this URL to upload the file to S3.

[image: Getting pre-signed URL]

**3. Hit the URL (PUT) with file**

Now, I hit the URL with HTTP method and I add the file (binary), see my Postman request:

[image]

You can see that I hit the request with the **PUT** HTTP Method. I get the 403 error. Here are the headers in the request and you can see that the content-type is `image/jpeg`:

[image]

When I try the **POST** method, I get that the signature is invalid. I guess that is because of the signature is signed for the PUT method.

[image]

Here is the S3 bucket's settings:

Since I get access denied, I completely opened the bucket, I mean `Block Public access: off`.

[image]

What is wrong with the settings? Maybe S3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a service object in the variable `s3` but you don't show, in your code, where that object was constructed... but it appears to be *before* you call `AWS.config.update()` which doesn't retroactively reconfigure your `s3` object.  The order of these operations is the problem.

> Updates you make to the global `AWS.config` object don't apply to previously created service objects.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/global-config-object.html

If you observe your generated URL closely you can see that the Lambda Execution Role credentials are actually being used, which is why access is denied.

The giveaways are that the AWSAccessKeyId in the URL is not yours, it's a session key beginning with `ASIA` instead of `AKIA` like a normal Access Key ID.  Also, there's a session token `x-amz-security-token` which wouldn't be there in a URL generated with static credentials.  Also this URL is Signature V2, so when you correct the credential configuration issue, the format of the signed URL will change significantly.  Signature V4 URLs have `X-Amz-Credential` instead of `AWSAccessKeyId`.

Comment: Amazing. I would have never found this. You were spot on 